# how do i create a single box search form with multiple values

Tags: php, jquery

OK, I have a real estate site, and I would like to create a single box search form that would allow the user to enter either city/state, or address, or price, or multiple search options, etc all in this one field and then of course it would return the results......sort of like the zillow or trulia search box.  I know how to create a standard form where where there are multiple fields for each type of data, but can anyone point me in the right direction for a single box that a user can input different search terms?

Answer (score 0):

Your search query has to combine the criteria using OR condition:

```
WHERE city=<search_term> or 
state=<search_term> or 
price between <search_term>-1000 and <search_term>+1000
```

and so on. Of course, ranking your query results by relevance is another story.